# python: Convert a Counter object to a json object with added key names

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a Counter object in Python, which contains the following data:

```
{'a': 4, 'b': 1, 'e': 1}
```

I'd like to convert this to a JSON object with the following form:

```
[{'name':'a', 'value': 4} , {'name':'b', 'value': 1}, {'name':'e', 'value': 1}]
```

Is there any efficient way to do so?

Comment: Is the order important?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to convert the dictionary to a list of dictionaries. Example -

```
data = {'a': 4, 'b': 1, 'e': 1}
result = [{'name':key, 'value':value} for key,value in data.items()]
```

Demo -

```
>>> data = {'a': 4, 'b': 1, 'e': 1}
>>> result = [{'name':key, 'value':value} for key,value in data.items()]
>>> result
[{'name': 'a', 'value': 4}, {'name': 'b', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'e', 'value': 1}]
```

Comment: `Counter(data).items()` will also work the same. Good solution.

Comment: We would still need the list comprehension or `map()` or so. `.items()` would only give a list of tuples.

Comment: I just meant that if you replace `data.items` with `Counter(data).items` in your solution -- no additional conversion of the Counter is needed